# video is not playing on chrome but playing in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a site in which I want to play video in background. Following is my code, video is playing in Internet explorer but not in Chrome. I'm using 2.2.4 version of jquery and I cannot change it because my all site is developed and If I change jquery than my whole site stops working.

```
<video id="vid" width="110%" height="100%" autoplay controls loop muted="muted">
  <source src="../img/led.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please post the output of the console for chrome

Comment: your chrome version should be greater than 4.0

Comment: @VikasUmrao: LOL! Good luck finding a copy of Chrome <4 in the wild...

Comment: *"...and If I change jquery than my whole site stops working"* Huh? jQuery's API is fairly stable. But I doubt jQuery is the problem here.

Comment: I was just suggesting to check this one also

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder don't know why people here are so overeacting... if i know the exact answer i have replied on answer section

Comment: Please gyz b calm

Comment: I mention jquery because video is playing with jquery function $j("vid").get(0).play(); which is in jquery-3.2.1